# Checking if a list contains a certain sequence of numbers

Tags: python

I have a list of 5 ints from 1 to 6 (simulating 5 dice rolling), randomly generated for example:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I want to check that if this list when sorted, contains either

```
[1,2,3,4] or [2,3,4,5] or [3,4,5,6].
```

How would I go about checking if list L contains any of the 3 combinations?
I don't want to have to go through and check if

```
L[i] == l1 [i],  L[i]== l2 [i],  L[i]== l3 [i]
```

for int in the list. I feel like its just a simple question of asking if the list contains either of the other lists or something. I'm just having trouble connecting the dots and its not clicking for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `in` operator is handy for seeing if a sequence contains a single item, but it doesn't work to check for a list of items. However, it does work on strings, so just convert everything to a string.

```
s = ''.join(str(i) for i in sorted(L))
if '1234' in s or '2345' in s or '3456' in s:
    # ...
```

If you had many more conditions to check for you could simplify a little:

```
if any(sublist in s for sublist in ('1234', '2345', '3456')):
```

Comment: I was thinking that this would break in conditions like [1,1,2,3,4] or [1,2,3,4,4] like a couple other things I tried, and it looks like it works for every situation.  This is not how I was imagining it being done, but I'll be damned it worked perfectly for what I was trying to do so I'll take it. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare to the first and last four elements of L:

```
 L = [1,2,3,4,5]
 lst = [2,3,4,5]
 print(sorted(lst) in (L[1:], L[:4]) )
```

So something like:

```
any(sorted(lst) in (L[1:],L[:4]) for lst in rolls)
```

Comment: So I am having a little trouble understanding what processes are all happening here, would you mind breaking it down for me? I am not sure what any() does.