# Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order

Tags: python

### code is no applicable for spy_games([1,0,3,0,4,7])##

```html
 def spy_games(arr):
          net=0
            for num in arr:
            if num==0:
            num +=net
            break
            if num==0:
            num +=net
            break
             if num==7:
                  return True
                else:
                 return False
```

Comment: where is the `spy_games` function

Comment: Please don't revert the question in a way that the correct code formatting you had goes away

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802019/checking-if-a-list-contains-a-certain-sequence-of-numbers) can also be used

Answer (score 1):

You can convert list of integers to string (e.g list `[1,0,3,0,6,7]` becomes `'103067'`) and then test if contains substring `'007'`:

```
list_of_integers1 = [1,0,3,0,6,7]
list_of_integers2 = [0,0,7,0,6,7]

def spy_games(arr):
    return '007' in ''.join(str(i) for i in arr)

print(spy_games(list_of_integers1))
print(spy_games(list_of_integers2))
```

Prints:

```
False
True
```

Comment: And can u please tell me ,what if i want the first input,which u write in the code,True.

Comment: @vishalmedavarapu just call e.g. `spy_games([0,0,7,0,6,7])` (in my code this is variable `list_of_integers2`.

Answer (score 1):

In your original approach, you are incrementing `num` when you see a `0` or a `7`, even when they are not close to each other like `[0,0,7]`, hence the current approach doesn't work

One approach to solve it to take a slice of length 3 while iterating over the list, and see if the slice matches `[0,0,7]`

```
def spy_games(li):

    #Iterate over the list
    for idx in range(len(li)):
        #If a slice of length 3 matches [0,0,7] return True
        if [0,0,7] == li[idx:idx+3]:
            return True

    #If no such slice found, return False
    return False

print(spy_games([1, 0, 3, 0, 6, 7]))
print(spy_games([1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7]))
print(spy_games([0, 0, 7, 1, 0, 3]))
print(spy_games([1, 0, 0, 7, 2, 3]))
```

The output will be

```
False
True
True
True
```

Comment: `for idx in range(0,len(li),3)` seems to be wrong because you won't catch `[1, 0, 0, 7, 2, 3]`. What about `for idx in range(len(li) - 3)`?

Comment: Thanks! You are correct, I had `step=3` defined in my list which caused that issue, I fixed it @Matthias Please take a look if it looks good now and consider upvoting if it does :)