# Conditional return Query

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is the below program right? It checks if the list has `1,2,3` sequence present.
Now, should the `else` statement be not in indentation with `if` line, rather than `for` line. As soon as I put it under `if`, other tests of this program go wrong. Please help explain.

```
def array123(nums):
  for x in range(len(nums)-2):
    if nums[x]==1 and nums[x+1]==2 and nums[x+2]==3:
      return True
  else:
    return False

array123([1, 1, 2, 3, 1])
```

Comment: Please format your code using `control + k` and try to simplify your problem as much as you can.

Comment: This is the [`for/else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) construct. The `else` will only be executed if the loop was exhausted without hitting the `break` statement inside the `if`. If you put the else inside the loop it will execute every time the condition is not met

Comment: Thank you! None of the books teach about this, just if/else construct.
So as a basic programmer, I would always do else after my if & never understand whts the error.

Comment: BTW, an alternative for this construct in your case can be using the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function: `return any(nums[x:x+3] == [1, 2, 3] for x in range(len(nums)-2))`

Comment: Thank you, read the similar post as well, much clear of this useless option. Thank you guys

Comment: Related (alternative solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802019/checking-if-a-list-contains-a-certain-sequence-of-numbers

Answer (score 0):

From here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

## 4.4. break and continue Statements, and else Clauses on Loops#

Loop statements may have an else clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the iterable (with for) or when the condition becomes false (with while), but not when the loop is terminated by a break statement. This is exemplified by the following loop, which searches for prime numbers:

```
>>> for n in range(2, 10):
...     for x in range(2, n):
...         if n % x == 0:
...             print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
...             break
...     else:
...         # loop fell through without finding a factor
...         print(n, 'is a prime number')
...
2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number
4 equals 2 * 2
5 is a prime number
6 equals 2 * 3
7 is a prime number
8 equals 2 * 4
9 equals 3 * 3
```

(Yes, this is the correct code. Look closely: the else clause belongs to the for loop, not the if statement.)

When used with a loop, the else clause has more in common with the else clause of a try statement than it does with that of if statements: a try statement’s else clause runs when no exception occurs, and a loop’s else clause runs when no break occurs. For more on the try statement and exceptions, see Handling Exceptions.

Comment: A query on this. I understood the whole other answers, but y is the 1st answer 2 is a prime number?
coz on the 1st run, wont it be 2%2 which is 0.. .
I know 2 is a prime number, but just asking about this program,

Comment: The inner for-loop does not enter the loop when n == 2 because range(2,2) == []

Comment: of course !!!!! Thanks !